# AppsFlyer with iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, appsflyer

I'm working on an existing project and haven't used AppsFlyer before.

in older version of AppsFlyer we have initialized it using these lines in AppDelegate

```
    AppsFlyerTracker.shared().appsFlyerDevKey = appsflyerKey
    AppsFlyerTracker.shared().appleAppID = appId

    AppsFlyerTracker.shared().trackAppLaunch()
```

And Track events using

```
     AppsFlyerTracker.shared().trackEvent("Started", withValues: prop)
```

But in the latest version of AppsFlyer the initial class name has changed from

```
AppsFlyerTracker -> AppsFlyerLib
// now event is logged by
AppsFlyerLib.shared().logEvent("Started", withValues: prop)
```

**So I have two questions**

1. As according to guide lines in iOS 14, we need to add permission for user to accept it before any tracking. **Is it applies to these AppsFlyers logEvent event too** ?
2. **if we need to add permission then  adding these lines will fill the purpose** ?

   AppsFlyerLib.shared().waitForATTUserAuthorization(timeoutInterval: 60)
   ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization { (status) in
   }
3. I didn't find alternate for **AppsFlyerTracker.shared().trackAppLaunch()** in the latest **AppsFlyerLib**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if user in above iOS 14 you must need to add these condition

based on your question :

> 1. As according to guide lines in iOS 14, we need to add permission for user to accept it before any tracking. Is it applies to these AppsFlyers logEvent event too ?

Ans : **YES**

> 2. if we need to add permission then adding these lines will fill the purpose ?

Ans : **YES**

initially you need to add the framework [**App Tracking Transparency**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apptrackingtransparency)

```
// The following block is optional for applications wishing to give users the option to block IDFA collection.
        // for iOS 14 and above - The user may be prompted to block IDFA collection.
        //                        If user opts-out, the IDFA will not be collected by the SDK.
        // for iOS 13 and below - The IDFA will be collected by the SDK. The user will NOT be prompted to block collection.
        if #available(iOS 14, *) {
            // Set a timeout for the SDK to wait for the IDFA collection before handling app launch
            // If timeout expires before user asks to block IDFA collection, the IDFA will be collected.
            AppsFlyerLib.shared().waitForATTUserAuthorization(timeoutInterval: 60)
            // Show the user the Apple IDFA consent dialog (AppTrackingTransparency)
            // MUST be called here before start() in order to prevent IDFA collection by the SDK
            ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization { (status) in
            }
        }
```

the above completion handler prompts the following two points

- The completion handler will be called with the result of the user's decision for granting or denying permission to use application tracking.
- The completion handler will be called immediately if access to request authorization is restricted.

and your final question

> I didn't find alternate for AppsFlyerTracker.shared().trackAppLaunch() in the latest AppsFlyerLib

Ans :

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Start the SDK (start the IDFA timeout set above, for iOS 14 or later)
    if #available(iOS 14, *) {
        AppsFlyerLib.shared().start()
    } else {
        AppsFlyerTracker.shared().trackAppLaunch()
    }
}
```

you can get the [sample project](https://github.com/AppsFlyerSDK/appsflyer-sdk-v6-sample-app) provided by AppsFlyer's team.